# Почему не поднимается Docker?

Tags: linux, docker, iptables, docker-compose, vagrant

Добрый день товарищи. Есть стэк:

- VirtualBox
- Vagrant
- Ubuntu server 16.04
- Docker

На VirtualBox я поставил и настроил Ubuntu Server 16.04, поставил Docker, собрал файл конфигурации **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "2"
services:
  nginx:
    restart: always
    image: "nginx:latest"         # Последняя версия Nginx
    container_name: "ls-nginx"    # Имя контейнера (ls - license server)
    ports:
      - "80:80"                   # Пробрасываем порты
    links:
      - php-fpm                   # Соединяем с php
    volumes:                      # Пробрасываем необходимые директории
      - ./logs/license-server/nginx/error.log:/var/log/license-server/nginx/error.log
      - ./containers/nginx/config/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./containers/nginx/license-server/license-server.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/license-server.conf
      - ./www/license-server:/var/www/license-server
    command: nginx -g "daemon off;" # Отрубаем режим демона

  php-fpm:
    restart: always
    image: php:7-fpm
    container_name: "ls-php-fpm"
    volumes:
      - ./logs/license-server/php-fpm/error.log:/var/log/license-server/php-fpm/error.log
      - ./www/license-server:/var/www/license-server
      - ./containers/php-fpm/php-cli.ini:/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/php-cli.ini
      - ./containers/php-fpm/php-fpm.ini:/etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/php-fpm.ini
      - ./containers/php-fpm/license-server/license-server.conf:/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/license-server.conf
    links:
      - db
      - redis
    # Переменные окружения
    environment:
      YII__DB__DRIVER: pdo_pgsql
      YII__DB__HOST: db
      YII__DB__PORT: 5432
      YII__DB__NAME: license-server
      YII__DB__USER: yii
      YII__DB__PASSWORD: 12345

  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always # При каждом перезапуске контейнера перезагружаем
    container_name: "ls-pgsql"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      # Путь для хранения файлов базы, если его нет,
      # после перезагрузки данные не сохранятся
      - ./databases/pgsql:/data/postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: license-server
      POSTGRES_USER: yii
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 12345
      PGDATA: /data/postgres

  adminer:
    restart: always
    image: adminer
    container_name: "ls-adminer"
    links:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

  redis:
    restart: always
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: "ls-redis"
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    volumes:
      - ./databases/redis:/var/lib/redis
    command: redis-server --appendonly yes
```

Для авто-запуска Docker после перезагрузки системы, добавил в **systemctl** конфиг **docker-license-server.service** и запустил `sudo systemctl enable docker-license-server.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Поднимаем окружение Docker c Nginx, FPM, PgSQL, Redis
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service

[Service]
Restart=always
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker-compose  -f /home/docker/apps/license-server/docker-compose.yml up
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker-compose  -f /home/docker/apps/license-server/docker-compose.yml down

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Завернул образ ОС в **Vagrant** по [этому](http://sysadm.pp.ua/linux/sistemy-virtualizacii/vagrant-box-creation.html) мануалу добавил конфиг **Vagrantfile**:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "Ubuntu_Server_16.04" # Имя бокса
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.111.55"
  config.vm.synced_folder "D:\\vagrant\\Projects", "/home/docker"
end
```

Всё поднимается, работает и вроде как все счастливы, но нет. При переносе Vagrant box-а на другую машину, появляются проблема. Собственно, стартует Vagrant, поднимается Docker, при заходе по url открывается локальный сайт, НО любые изменения в файлах проекта, не отображаются при обновлении страницы.

Что я уже проверил:

- id developer и id vagrant находятся в группы docker
- При попытке вручную поднять docker через команду: `docker-compose up
  -d` я получаю ошибку вида:

> Creating network "licenseserver_default" with the default driver
>   ERROR: Failed to program FILTER chain: iptables failed: iptables --wait -I FORWARD -o br-66b3a1ad4668 -j DOCKER: iptables v1.6.0: Couldn't load target DOCKER':No such file or directory
>
> Try iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.

- Проверил файл проекта на сервере, всё в порядке, в файле находятся все мои изменения.
- Пробовал настраивать в `/etc/default/docker` `DOCKER_OPTS="--iptables=false"`
  (На другой машине этого файла вообще нет, пришлось создавать вручную) не помогло

Проблему временно устраняет [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33600154/docker-not-starting-could-not-delete-the-default-bridge-network-network-bridg/33604859#33604859) солюшен.
 
Мы сбрасываем настройки сети вручную, посредством команды:

`sudo mv /var/lib/docker/network/files/ /tmp/dn-bak`

И перезагружаем демон Docker:

`sudo service docker restart`

Но после перезапуска виртуальной машины, всё по новой. Это не есть гуд.
Помогите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

**P.S.** Самое странное, что на моей машине всё работает ок (пробовал разворачивать окружение в другой папке, всё гуд), а на другой машине такие проблемы.

Comment: Добрый день! а права на диск с данными виртуальной машины проверяли .vmdk файл? Еще покажите вывод docker-compose ps после запуска docker-compose up -d. Сравните настрйки интерфейса через ifconfig и цепочек правил iptables -L на рабочей\не рабочей машине. При переносе виртуальной машины тушили ее полностью или на паузу поставили?

Comment: @СергейГамов приветствую! Пока могу сказать лишь что, права на диск не проверял, машину переносил в виде тэмплэйта, вагрант сам всё распаковывает. Мануал по упаковке и распаковке, по которому я все делал, есть в сообщении. При переносе, виртуальная машина была выключена полностью.

Comment: Есть предположение, сам я его не проверял, но может у Вас получится проверить. Когда вы подняли docker-compose в исходном окружении - docker-engine создал сеть "licenseserver_default" и привязал ее к интерфейсу br-66b3a1ad4668. Затем вы создали тимплейт и перенесли его на другую машину и после разворачивания тимплейта при запуске - docker-engine попросту не смог найти интерфейс br-66b3a1ad4668 так как он уже вероятно имеет другое имя. Попробуйте на виртуалке удалить сеть "licenseserver_default" (docker network rm "licenseserver_default") и еще раз поднять docker-compose. Версия вроде логичная)

Comment: @СергейГамов приветствую. Путём долго ресёрча, нашёл временное решение, которое возможно выведет нас к итоговому варианту. В общем, проблема была с iptables. Когда docker запускается, он прописывает правила в iptables для DOCKER и DOCKER-ISOLATION. Во всяком случае на рабочей машине всё именно так. На нерабочей, правил либо вообще нет, их приходится заводить руками `sudo iptables -N DOCKER` и `sudo iptables -N DOCKER-ISOLATION`, либо они не верны. Т.е. в файлах проекта отображается не тот файл. Лечится перезапуском docker-compose.

Comment: @СергейГамов  В связи с вышесказанным, возникают 3 вопроса. 1) Почему правила для iptables DOCKER и DOCKER-ISOLATION не сохранились после оборачивания образа в Vagrant template если они присутствуют в системе. 2) Почему docker после авто-запуска через systemd стартует, но не видит sync.folder с основной ОС. 3) Как сделать, чтобы всё было кошерно! :) Спасибо

Comment: по 1 - попробуйте не запуская docker-compose создать типлейт, и уже после разворачивания из тимплейта при запуске docker-compose up пусть docker-engine сам все сделает (я думаю это решит проблему с iptables), 2 - sync.folder прописан в vagrant и монтируется как волум внутри docker? тогда нужно разрешения смотреть. 3 - все и так кошерно вы же используете docker! :)